# Mask UIImage with UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, core-graphics, mask

I'm trying to mask a UIImage with another UIImage in Swift.
The desired result is achieved when I run the code in a xcode playground but not when I run the same code in on a simulator.
[image: Desired output as seen in xcode playground]

[image: Output as seen in simulator]

This is the code I run:

```
func maskImage(image: UIImage, maskImage: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
    let size = image.size
    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size)

    // Begin graphics
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }

    context.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: image.size.height)
    context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

    let mask = maskImage.cgImage

    context.clip(to: rect, mask: mask!)
    context.draw(image.cgImage!, in: rect)

    let img =  UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return img
}
```

The documentation of `.clip(to rect: CGRect, mask: CGImage)` says:

> If the mask parameter is an image, then mask acts like an alpha mask
>   and is blended with the current clipping area.

I assume this is why the second picture has an alpha mask instead. But how do I get the desired output as in the first picture? And why is playground showing the correct result and not the simulator?

Side note: `CGImage.masking(_ mask: CGImage) -> CGImage?` also results in an alpha mask.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same images? I just tried your exact code and got identical results in Playground and Simulator and Device, using 3 different image mask types:  http://imgur.com/a/2moQn

Comment: @DonMag, thanks for helping out! Yes, I'm using the same images. I've tried both pngs and jpgs but with the same result. Also tried on device with same result.

Comment: Well, if you're using the *same* images and the *exact same* code, and getting different results, something else must be going on. Try creating a new Playground file and a new app project, and see what happens. Perhaps a file got corrupted somewhere.